# Auto Differentiation in Deep Learning Libraries

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, algorithms, automatic-differentiation

It is said that **auto-diff is very efficient** in generating the derivatives for backpropagation algorithms. The why is it that some of the most widely used **deep learning libraries like Theano and TensorFlow do not use** this functionality? Is it because of difference implementation views or **is there some drawback of auto-diff** that has kept them away from it?

Comment: Yes it does... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370129/does-tensorflow-use-automatic-or-symbolic-gradients